# Limiting map tips popups by scale in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, maptips

I have a points later and have enabled map tips to appear when I hover, as normal. However, I would like to prevent map tips balloons from appearing when zoomed out. The way I have found to accomplish this so far is to duplicate the points layer and set the point symbols to transparent, enable map tips in that layer, and disable in the original layer, and then limit the visibility of this new layer entirely. However, I'd like to think there is a more elegant way of limiting the popups from appearing when zoomed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use an `if` expression and the variable `@map_scale` to create a map tip with a conditional scale rule.

Using the expression

```html
[% if( @map_scale <10, 'your text here','')%]
```

the map tip will appear only if the scale is less than 10.

[image]

If you want to define a range of min/max scales where the map tips will appear, you can use a double conditional, e.g. to show tips only if the scale is bigger than 10 and smaller than 25

```
[% if(@map_scale <25,
if( @map_scale >10, 'your text here',''),'') %]
```